# How do I use a font from Windows 10 and install it in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, fonts

There is a font called Bahnschift and I've been wanting to use this font for some projects but unfortunately when I tried to install this font (I'm trying to install the whole font family), all that installs is just Bahnschift Regular and nothing else. I even tried to transfer fonts from an old Windows 10 computer to my Windows 8.1 laptop and it still didn't work, it keeps telling me that The font is installed, Do you want to replace the font?

I thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Banhnschrift font is a variable font. Variable fonts are not supported on Windows 8.1 or below.

For variable fonts that use CFF2 outline data, the font will not work at all on older implementations that don't support variable fonts. If the variable font uses TrueType outlines, then the default instance—and only the default instance—will work in older implementations. In the case of Bahnschrift (and many other variable fonts), the default instance is "Regular".

Comment: oh well, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the correctly installed font from your windows 10 computer, it should be in the `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder, and then pasting it in the same folder on your Windows 8 machine, taking care of deleting eventual fonts with the same name first.

Comment: I did that, but there was still the same font problem

Comment: Copying fonts from one Windows system to use on an earlier version may be violating the EULA.